# Spark XML Parser is not writing output in correct format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I have to fire an SQL query get the output and write that into either XML or Json File Format.

I have written a program to do it but somehow i am not getting the expected output. I am representing my SQL output as 'str' in this question. Basically my SQL Stored Proc returns XML string as an output.

```
String str = "<?xml version="1.0"?> \n"
            "<ROWSET> \n"
               +"<ROW> \n"
                +"<CTLCORP>001</CTLCORP> \n"
                +"<CTLDIV>05</CTLDIV> \n"
                +"<CTLFAC>2563</CTLFAC> \n"
                +"<CTLVEND_NUM>001878</CTLVEND_NUM> \n"
                +"<CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT>002</CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT> \n"
                +"<CTLCORP_ITEM_CD>75552874</CTLCORP_ITEM_CD> \n"
                +"<CTLSRC_CD>DISC</CTLSRC_CD> \n"
               +"</ROW> \n"
             +"</ROWSET>";


    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Build a DataFrame from Scratch").master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext  = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());                                    

    List<String> stringAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringAsList.add(str);

    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((String row) -> {return RowFactory.create(row);});

    // Creates schema
    StructType schema = DataTypes
            .createStructType(new StructField[] { DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, false)});      


    Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
    df.show();              

    df.coalesce(1)
        .write()
        .mode("overwrite")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") 
        .save("./Output/XMLOutput");

    /*
    df.coalesce(1)
        .write()
        .mode("overwrite")      
        .json("./Output/JSONOutput");   
    */
```

This program is giving output like this when i am writing it as XML file format.

```
<ROWS>
    <ROW>
        <value>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
    &lt;ROWSET&gt;
     &lt;ROW&gt;
      &lt;CTLCORP&gt;001&lt;/CTLCORP&gt;
      &lt;CTLDIV&gt;03&lt;/CTLDIV&gt;
      &lt;CTLFAC&gt;2563&lt;/CTLFAC&gt;
      &lt;CTLVEND_NUM&gt;001878&lt;/CTLVEND_NUM&gt;
      &lt;CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT&gt;002&lt;/CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT&gt;
      &lt;CTLCORP_ITEM_CD&gt;75552874&lt;/CTLCORP_ITEM_CD&gt;
      &lt;CTLSRC_CD&gt;SSIMS&lt;/CTLSRC_CD&gt;      
     &lt;/ROW&gt;
    &lt;/ROWSET&gt;
    </value>
    </ROW>
</ROWS>
```

Expected Output in XML file Format

```
<ROWSET> 
                   <ROW> 
                    <CTLCORP>001</CTLCORP> 
                    <CTLDIV>03</CTLDIV> 
                    <CTLFAC>2563</CTLFAC> 
                    <CTLVEND_NUM>001878</CTLVEND_NUM> 
                    <CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT>002</CTLVEND_SUB_ACNT> 
                    <CTLCORP_ITEM_CD>75552874</CTLCORP_ITEM_CD> 
                    <CTLSRC_CD>SSIMS</CTLSRC_CD>                         
                   </ROW> 
                  </ROWSET>
```

Can someone suggest what i am doing wrong here? I need to have proper XML tags when i want to write it as output. Here in my ouput you can see i am getting something like '&lt', '&gt'. Not sure why.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Do you have a solution to this scenario? Please let me know! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame schema is wrong; it says that ROW has one field, value, that is a String. You get what you ask for there: the string (which happens to be XML) appears as an escaped child of value.

You need to start with a DataFrame that matches you intended schema.

If you already have the XML though, why do you need to write anything except that XML you already have?

Comment: One of my column has values containing symbol < ( less than ). This gets converted to &lt; in the output XML file.
How can I get around this issue ?

Comment: That is actually correct behavior!